# mod_python not detecting files when using open()

Tags: python, apache2, mod-python

I am trying to open a file I have in my /var/www/ directory named cardlist.xml.
this is the code I am using.

```
import cgi
import os
open("./cardlist.xml", "r")
def crawlXml():
    return 0
```

My error is

> MOD_PYTHON ERROR
>
> ProcessId:      11361 Interpreter:
>   '127.0.1.1'
>
> ServerName:     '127.0.1.1'
>   DocumentRoot:   '/var/www'
>
> URI:            '/test.py/crawlXml'
>   Location:       None Directory:
>   '/var/www/' Filename:
>   '/var/www/test.py' PathInfo:
>   '/crawlXml'
>
> Phase:          'PythonHandler'
>   Handler:        'mod_python.publisher'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
>       default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 1229, in _process_target
>       result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 1128, in _execute_target
>       result = object(arg)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/publisher.py",
>   line 204, in handler
>       module = page_cache[req]
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 1059, in **getitem**
>       return import_module(req.filename)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 296, in import_module
>       log, import_path)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 680, in import_module
>       execfile(file, module.**dict**)
>
> File "/var/www/test.py", line 4, in
>   
>       open("./cardlist.xml", "r")
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: './cardlist.xml'
>
> MODULE CACHE DETAILS
>
> Accessed:       Sun Feb 14 16:59:58
>   2010 Generation:     19
>
> _mp_27cc55c5447f9e0aa13691719290c225 {   FileName:     '/var/www/test.py'
>   Instance:     85 [RELOAD]
>   Generation:   19 [ERROR]   Modified:
>   Sun Feb 14 16:40:17 2010   Imported:
>   Sun Feb 14 16:22:38 2010 }

This is the result of ls -la in the

> /var/www/ directory drwxr-xr-x  3 root
>   root    4096 2010-02-14 16:40 .
>   drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    4096
>   2010-02-14 15:05 ..
>   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4612891 2010-01-30 16:39 cardlist.xml
>   drwxrwx---  3 root root    4096
>   2010-02-14 14:31 mtg
>   -rw-r--r--  1 root root     110 2010-02-14 16:40 test.py
>   -rw-r--r--  1 root root     111 2010-02-14 16:32 test.py~

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: 1. Have you tried an absolute path? 2. What does `os.path.abspath('./cardlist.xml')` return?

Comment: os.path.abspath('./cardlist.xml') returns /cardlist.xml
I am not sure what an 'absolute path' would be for this. /var/www/cardlist.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working directory might not be the directory of the file.  Try using an absolute path, or an explicitly relative path:

```
import os.path
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'cardlist.xml'))
```